# Is Most Excellent Adventure available anywhere other than 1d4 chan?

Tags: product-identification, online-resources

Most Excellent Adventure, to my knowledge is a free time-travel RPG based on Bill and Ted's Most Excellent Adventure.

To my recollection, the only copy available was hosted on [1d4chan](http://1d4chan.org/wiki/Most_Excellent_Adventure). However that is now down, and I don't know where else it's hosted. Googling hasn't turned up anything for me the last time I looked.

This is not the same as [TimeWatch](http://site.pelgranepress.com/index.php/timewatch/).

The dice mechanic relied on dialling a number based on the roll on your dice pool, and featured this diagram

[image: Two phone dialling pads, showing connected sequences of dice rolls.]

I have found a ***potentially unsafe*** pdf hosted on `i.4pcdn.org` (visit at your own risk). It looks exactly like the game I remember, but without knowing who is hosting it, if the PDF is safe and confirming it's the whole pdf I'm not confident it's the exact game.

Finding out who made the game, would go a long way into making sure it was the right game and that it was a safe copy.

Comment: The graphic came from [a previous question I posted on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205049/what-are-my-chances-in-a-most-excellent-adventure), but the link there is just to 1d4chan again, which does not work.

Comment: Curious the link you posted now works, moreover it does have a GDrive link to the same document you linked you self-answered.

Comment: 1d4chan appears to be up now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first draft of the game came from [this thread](http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/18389513/), post [No.18410350](http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/18389513/#18410350) by [Anonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4chan#cite_ref-15) on 03/21/12 (Wed) at 21:25.

That post contains a link to the google drive [document](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9iXY4btM829ZnlqY1RVckVRWE9nZFFETWJGa3RYQQ), and the other posts in that thread document how the game was developed.

Answer (score 15):

Using the wayback machine on that [link](https://web.archive.org/web/2020*/https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Most_Excellent_Adventure) gives a page with a link to a [google drive document](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9iXY4btM829ZnlqY1RVckVRWE9nZFFETWJGa3RYQQ/edit).